# pyspark error :java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.18] failure: identifier expected

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to do a filter on a DataFrame of people in the organization of ABC's and branch name like ABC'S:

```
 people.filter(" orgnization = ABC\'S and branch like '%ABC\'S%'  ").show()
```

Here is the error I got

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o47.filter.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.18] failure: identifier expected
```

Comment: what is `like` supposed to do?

Comment: branch name  is something like ABC'S  and allow something before and after ABC'S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should:

- Enclose  all strings inside single or double quotes.
- Depending on the choice of the enclosing quotes escape embedded quote and backslash.

Let's explain this by example. Here's the data:

```
df = sc.parallelize([("ABC'S", "FOO ABC'S")]).toDF(["organization", "branch"])
```

If you decide to use single quotes you have to escape embedded quote as well as backslash.

```
df.filter("""organization='ABC\\'S' and branch like '%ABC\\'S%'""")
```

If you decide to use double quotes you may skip escaping completely:

```
df.filter('''organization="ABC'S"  and branch like "%ABC'S%"''')
```

In general you'll save yourself a lot of troubleshooting by replacing SQL strings with method calls:

```
df.where((df["organization"] == "ABC'S") & df["branch"].like("%ABC'S"))
```